# Best practice for a group of similar functions

Tags: php, object-oriented-design

I’ve built a small little library that I think really aids in PHP development. It makes secure by default database transactions, makes cURL requesting anything easy (including files), and it has a bunch of methods for handling and sanitizing different data (phone numbers, emails, etc...) it’s this last part that I have my question about.

I have all of those methods in a class called HandleData. They are all static methods that take the data you want to sanitize and validate and either return the sanitized data or FALSE on validation failure. So like this
        $safe_email = HandleData::email(‘someone@example.com’);

My question is this: is putting them in a class the best practice thing to do, even though the class can’t be initialized and all the methods are static? Or should I do it some other way?

Comment: It’s just more work to make them non static via a wrapper for your users. Making them non static by definition would take you less than 5 seconds. Also, HandleData does not mean anything. A class is supposed to handle data in some way so you could’ve named this “Class”. Make the API easier to discover and understand by separating this god object into classes focused on one behaviour. I don’t know why doing curl requests and sanitising emails should have anything in common, especially the location in the source code.

Comment: So I guess my wording was unclear, the library (ShinePHP) is comprised of three classes: Crud (the database interaction class), HttpRequest (the Http helper one), and HandleData. HandleData has 9 static methods that validate and sanitize phone numbers, emails, IP addresses, etc.....so my question is, what is the best coding practice for those 9 static methods in HandleData? Because the reason the three classes are grouped together anyways is because they are all basic things that any Crud based PHP app needs (at least those are the three things I reach for the most)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you were not the one who has written this library, but someone else. You don't know the lib, but you get the task of reusing functions from it if possible. Now you want to check if it contains a specific functionality for your current email-related use case.

- do you think you would find out easily there is function "email" in it - among 100 other functions in `HandleData` dealing with different topics -  which does exactly what you want`?
- or do you think it will be easier if there is a class `EmailHelper` which contains a function `sanitizeEmailAddress` - among only ten other functions, all dealing with the topic of emails?

I don't know what you prefer, but I would probably go for the second alternative.

And please stop thinking in terms of "braindead best practices". Start to think in terms of "what helps you or your team most in the current situation". If a class like "HandleData" has only 5 methods, I would probably not bother in separating it to different classes. The class name maybe not a good one, but sometimes you have no idea of a better name, and inventing a better one is not worth the hassle. But when a class grows and gets more and more different responsibilities, don't miss the point where you should start to refactor it into separate responsibilites, otherwise your code ends up becoming a "big-ball-of-mud".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, wrapping your functions in a class is probably a good idea.

In some other languages the class would be unnecessary, and it would be better to just write stand-alone functions. But PHP classes have one big advantage over functions - they can be loaded on demand via [autoloading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Standard practice is to distribute libraries via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), which provides an autoloader.

If you took the functions out of the class, you would need to either arrange for the file containing the functions to be included all the time in applications using your library, which may be wasteful, or find some other mechanism to ensure they are loaded when required, which is likely to be a lot more cumbersome than relying on Composer's autoloader.